# How to escape double quotes?

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a function that generates a `clob` with xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OBJECT_TYPES meta_version="1.0"><OBJECT_TYPE type_name="Absorber "Geo""/>
</OBJECT_TYPES>
```

When I try to escape double quote with `\"` I get an error:

> Error: Required white space was missing. Line: (1) `<OBJECT_TYPE
>   type_name="Absorber \"Geo\""/>`

I can't understand why it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to escape a double quote character inside a double-quoted attribute value in XML is to use `&quot;`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OBJECT_TYPES meta_version="1.0"><OBJECT_TYPE type_name="Absorber &quot;Geo&quot;"/>
</OBJECT_TYPES>
```

Alternatively you can use single quotes around the attribute value which then allows literal double quotes within it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OBJECT_TYPES meta_version="1.0"><OBJECT_TYPE type_name='Absorber "Geo"'/>
</OBJECT_TYPES>
```

Similarly, to escape single quote characters within a single-quoted attribute you use `&apos;`

```
<OBJECT_TYPE type_name='Ian&apos;s type'/>
```

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that question is talking about HTML, not XML - `&apos;` is always valid in XML documents.